# How to debug iOS7 shadowOffset crash

Tags: ios, ios7

My app works fine on ios6.  I made a copy and ran it on Xcode5 and it launches but a few seconds later it crashes with this error:

```
[UIDeviceRGBColor shadowOffset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I had some tableviewcontroller lines like this:

```
//[[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

but I commented them all out thinking they were the issue.  What else could be causing the crash?

Comment: We still can not discuss iOS 7 or XCode 5 yet because they are under NDA

Comment: True but clearly this code worked fine in iOS6. I understand it is something that changed in iOS7 then. Thus the code I presented up here is iOS6 code. I posted it in the devforums, could anyone help there?

Comment: Well I found the cause in case anyone is interested you can email me or chat.

Comment: That is what the Apple developer forums are for. Please do not post about this here, violating Apple's policies.

Answer (score 0):

```
//do this to see if the selector exists replace dismissViewController... with your selector that you want to check
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:)])
        {[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];} //post-iOS6.0
else {[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];} //pre-iOS6.0
```